# How should I design my PosgreSQL database to accommodate Private, Group, and Public Chat?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, chat

I am creating a small messaging application in which a user can send messages to:

- General Chat - (Anyone and everyone)
- Private Chat - (Between 2 Users)
- Group Chat   - (3+ Users)

I am still new to database design and would like some insight on how to design my database.

What is a good design/schema that would allow me to have these capabilities?

Right now I have a schema that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE ChatRooms (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
);


CREATE TABLE ChatMessages (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
roomID FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL,
message VARCHAR(100),
senderID FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL, 
time TIMESTAMP
);
```

And also a User table with userID of course. Do I need any more tables?

Comment: What are you asking broad and avoiding use column name like `id` better `roomID` too. And you need to know what requirement in this 3 chat `general,group,private`

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble understanding what you wrote, could you please rephrase it?

Comment: you have table `ChatMessages` and `ChatRooms` with their primary key `id` that's not good naming it would be better represent the table name with `id` as the last letter and i say broad because you have 3 chat or table `general`,`group`,`private` you need to know the requirement you need.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designs i would suggest:

```
**ChatRooms**        **ChatMessages**    **ChatUsers**
room_id              id                  user_id
serial               room_id             room_id
type (0/1/2)         sender_id           added_on (timestamp)
users (user count)   text
                     time (timestamp)
```

Now that "type" will indicate weather that room is general(0) , group(1) or private(2).
Whenever a user joins a chatroom  their information will be added to ChatUsers table with the specific chatroom id and as they leave that chatroom that row will be deleted from ChatUsers table. The benefit of ChatUsers table is that when you will display total users in a room you will not have to count all the rows from the ChatUsers table instead you will just pick the value from ChatRooms table of column 'users' which is equal to the rows of specfic room in ChatUsers table, you will need to increment the room's users column everytime a row is added to the ChatUsers table and also decrement when a row is deleted with the room's id.You can also display the information of the users in a room by picking the 'user_id' column values from the rows which have the specific room's id in column 'room_id' and then retrieve the information of the following users with those ids from the user table.

I hope this is what you were looking for.